# Past simple- present perfect no time reference

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, simple-past

I have a doubt between the usage of past simple and present perfect about the meaning of “indefinite past”
If I don’t mention or it’s not clear a time expression, Could I use the PP instead o PS?
For example:
I’ve interviewed him (some time in the past)
I’ve bought a car (doesn’t matter when)

Thank you

Comment: Both of those example sentences are fine. In the right context (such as in response to *Who's interviewed him?* or *Has anybody here bought a car?*), both of those sentences are more natural than sentences with another tense.